# Has anyone tried out Hero Scale to autoscale Heroku apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

https://www.heroscale.com/

Any feedback or suggestions? 
I'm think about going with this route in case I need to scale my rails app.

**EDIT****
I just signed up and according to their site, they've been down since February.

Comment: I'm sceptical of the idea. The gem you install exposes a JSON packet of backlog and queue depth (as far as I remember). If all your dynos are busy how does this get displayed? If it times out/errors does that then prompt it to scale?

Comment: you've prompted me to re-investigate this... http://www.hirefireapp.com looks like my favourite so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just signed up and according to their site, they've been down since February.

Answer (score 1):

http://hirefireapp.com/ looks like it has traction.

Answer (score 0):

HireFire.io (formerly HireFireApp.com) has been going strong the past 2 years and is constantly improving. It can auto-scale your web and worker dynos. It supports virtually any language/framework. We provide two Metric Sources at this time: HireFire and NewRelic. The HireFire Metric Source performs a simple HTTP request to measure response times, and the NewRelic Metric Source actually uses New Relic's metrics. You can use their Response Time metric which considers request queuing, databases queries/performance, app-layer performance, router, etc. Or, you could use their Apdex Score metric which allows you to scale based on user experience / satisfaction.

Using the New Relic Metric Source you get best of both worlds, a tool built for performance monitoring with great visualization through graphs, and a tool built for auto-scaling.

Disclaimer: I built HireFire.